Pandas v1.0.1 vs v 2.0.3 read_csv and/or parse_dates Differences
I am receiving different behavior when ingesting a csv file using two different Python installations on two different machines. I suspect the problem lies in the difference of Pandas versions, but I suppose it could be elsewhere among the Python installations.
Pandas v1.0.1 will always parse the input date/time field as intended and expected. The dataframe always returns a datatype of "datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(-480)]". On the Pandas v2.0.3 install, the exact same dataset will sometimes return "datetime64[ns, UTC-08:00]", but more often it returns "object". It then throws the error "Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values".
Clearly something has changed under the hood. While I could accomplish my goal by running on the older install, I want to modernize to current versions. The unpredictability of the v2.0.3 output is gettin in my way.
Here is what I believe to be the relevant code.
Note: The previous programmer deliberately defined data types as str as I assume the dates were getting garbled. That was using a previous and different non-CSV file format. I'm not sure if I still need this, but commenting it out didn't seem to make a difference. That's if I remember correctly in all of my debug flailing.
    # Force read_csv to interpret everything as text, so it doesn't re-format any numbers (e.g., DateTime)
    data_types = {
                  'DateTime': str,
                  'Temperature(F)': str,
                  'RelativeHumidity(%)': str,
                  'Precipitation(in)': str,
                  'WindSpeed(mph)': str,
                  'WindAzimuth(degrees)': str,
                  'SolarRadiation(W/m2)': str,
                  'SnowFlag': str,
                  'GustSpeed(mph)': str,
                  'GustAzimuth(degrees)': str,
                  ' Temperature(F)': str,
                  ' RelativeHumidity(%)': str,
                  ' Precipitation(in)': str,
                  ' WindSpeed(mph)': str,
                  ' WindAzimuth(degrees)': str,
                  ' SolarRadiation(W/m2)': str,
                  ' SnowFlag': str,
                  ' GustSpeed(mph)': str,
                  ' GustAzimuth(degrees)': str,
                  'Tflag': str,
                  'RHflag': str,
                  'PCPflag': str,
                  'WSflag': str,
                  'WAflag': str,
                  'SRflag': str,
                  'GSflag': str,
                  'GAflag': str,
                  }

    processed = 0  # Track how many files are processed

    # list to store only .fw21 files
    files = []
    # Iterate directory
    for file in os.listdir(fw21_dir):
        # check only fw21 files
        if file.endswith('.fw21'):
            files.append(file)

    print(f"{len(files)} .fw21 files found.")

    for f in files:

        print(f"processing {f}")
        
        outname = f.replace('.fw21', '_REFORMATTED.csv')
        outfile = os.path.join(out_dir, outname)
         # Read input file into Pandas dataframe
        fw21_data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(fw21_dir, f), parse_dates=['DateTime'], dtype = data_types)
        
        print(fw21_data.dtypes)

When the error is thrown by v2.0.3, this is the offending line:
fw21_data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(fw21_dir, f), parse_dates=['DateTime'], dtype = data_types)

And this is the error:
  File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\pandas\core\indexes\accessors.py:580 in __new__
    raise AttributeError("Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values")

Here is an input .csv file snippet. Each input file has 200,000+ lines and there are 140+ input files.
DateTime, Temperature(F), RelativeHumidity(%), Precipitation(in), WindSpeed(mph), WindAzimuth(degrees), SolarRadiation(W/m2), SnowFlag, GustSpeed(mph), GustAzimuth(degrees),Tflag,RHflag,PCPflag,WSflag,WAflag,SRflag,GSflag,GAflag
 2000-01-01T00:00:00-08:00,37,100,00.12,3,262,0,0,22,242,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,0
 2000-01-01T01:00:00-08:00,36,100,00.01,3,237,0,0,15,240,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,0
 2000-01-01T02:00:00-08:00,36,100,00.01,5,219,0,0,17,239,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,0
 2000-01-01T03:00:00-08:00,36,100,00.03,5,232,0,0,22,198,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,0
 2000-01-01T04:00:00-08:00,36,100,00.04,6,224,0,0,21,220,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,0
 2000-01-01T05:00:00-08:00,36,100,00.03,7,221,0,0,28,225,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,0
 2000-01-01T06:00:00-08:00,32,100,00.11,7,281,0,0,37,235,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0
 2000-01-01T07:00:00-08:00,32,100,00.01,6,304,0,0,17,325,0,0,2,2,0,1,0,0
 2000-01-01T08:00:00-08:00,33,100,00.01,6,330,15,0,20,314,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,0
 2000-01-01T09:00:00-08:00,34,100,00.00,5,291,74,0,20,279,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,0
 2000-01-01T10:00:00-08:00,33,100,00.02,5,289,142,0,28,320,0,0,2,2,0,1,0,0
 2000-01-01T11:00:00-08:00,32,100,00.03,4,296,129,0,23,312,0,0,2,2,0,1,0,0


what about df[DateTime] = pd.to_datetime(df["DateTime"])

also if you are going to read into str anyways, dtype=object should clean the code.

@BijayRegmi
Changing 'DateTime': str, to 'DateTime': object, didn't produce a significant change. Similar to my previous randomness, the first file typed as "datetime64[ns, UTC-08:00]" but then the second file typed as "object" and then errored out. I'll try your first solution next.

I don't know if this rises to the level of a bug, but @BijayRegmi's first offering led me to a working solution.
Near as I can tell, there is some randomness where Pandas hiccups when parsing DateTime fields. I tried:
fw21_data['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(fw21_data['DateTime'])

but then received the following error:
ValueError: time data "2013-09-25T02:00:00-08:00" doesn't match format " %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z", at position 120386. You might want to try:
- passing `format` if your strings have a consistent format;
- passing `format='ISO8601'` if your strings are all ISO8601 but not necessarily in exactly the same format;
- passing `format='mixed'`, and the format will be inferred for each element individually. You might want to use `dayfirst` alongside this.

The pandas DateTime parser would not recognize occasional entries in the DateTime field, even though the offending input line looks just like all the other 200,000+ lines in that file.
I initially looked up the available parameters for to_datetime and saw:
errors='coerce'

and then discovered that (just like the documentation stated) it sets the offending value to NaT...not the desired outcome.
So for my working solution, I left alone the data typing for:
'DateTime': str,

I then modified:
fw21_data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(fw21_dir, f), parse_dates=['DateTime'], dtype = data_types)

to the following with the key added part being format='ISO8601'), since it was that format:
fw21_data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(fw21_dir, f), dtype = data_types)
fw21_data['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(fw21_data['DateTime'],format='ISO8601')

That seems to have bridged the problem after testing 16 input files so far. I'm open to any other feedback or ideas.
